# ALSA Keeps Throwing Me Errors, really Frustrating

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, alsa

## The Situation

So my sound cards aren't totally fried, and everything works fine, it's just annoying when working with python scripts and [Speech Recognition for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/). This being  the result of my works, I found nothing more then I already knew with a quick [Google Search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+fix+ALSA+lib+pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open)+unable+to+open+slave). I went ahead and decided to put all my effort I possibly could into making this post as well, as to help future people who encounter the same error as me perhaps find an answer like I hopefully do. I know more people are having this problem, but I just can't find the right solution to it.

## The Error Code

I thought that I would be helpful to people who are wondering what I'm exactly doing to *"cause"* this error of mine, so I would display using a simple image, a png, of my exact actions. Get ready because it's *amazing*.

**I go into terminal, and do this**

[image: What Im Doing]

As you all can see, I clearly tried **reloading** the darned thing, *but the illusive error code still confuzzles me*. I also took into account trying to point out, just to go the extra mile, and paste my error code that I'm so confused about.

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

I know from the start that ALSA is an abreviation and I immediately went to their [Site & Wiki](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) to try and learn more about my error. Nope, nothing. Not even remotely close to figuring something out. I don't honestly know what it is, but it's not major, it doesn't hinder me from programming my pythons, but it is annoying when checking for errors and responses from speech recognition. I just want a method to the madness really, if someone could be as kind enough to point me in the right direction or even answer me with a good sized guide, because I am but a wee Linux user, only a month old. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks all!

Comment: Some code tries to open a device that does not exist. But if it works, it has found a device eventually.

Comment: @CL. I know that, I mean not trying to be offensive, but I knew that coming into the post. What I was asking though,  was how to essentially "_silence_"  these errors.